# looking for files and make backup but keep running into error

Tags: powershell, file, directory, copy-item

this seemed to be a good way to make a backup of my files without having to search of them manualy

I use the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.7z, *.rar, *.zip, *.db, *.sql, *.bmp, *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.odp, *.pps, *.ppt, *.pptx, *.ods, *.xls, *.xlsx, *.doc, *.docx, *.pdf, *.rtf, *.txt | % { Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination c:\Test>> }
```

this seem to be working fine on Windows 7 but now I keep running into the following error:

```
Copy-Item : De cloudbestandprovider wordt niet uitgevoerd.
At line:1 char:180
+ ...  *.pdf, *.rtf, *.txt | % { Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination c:\Test
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

not sure what I did wrong here, anyone able to help me out and help me fix the error?
was unable to figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had to translate the error you got, but 'The cloud file provider is not running' means that you have OneDrive or something like that setup in File On Demand mode, which means that the local files don't actually exist and are just representative of a file in your cloud storage. You can turn off the File On Demand feature in your cloud backup solution, and that should resolve the issue. The error occurs because it is trying to copy a file that doesn't actually exist on the computer.